# how to make Webrtc support my Safari browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, webrtc

have developed a small video chat application using Webrtc . it works exactly fine in my other set of browsers (chrome,firefox,opera)... but it doesnt supports Safari .. please can one help me out in this,to make my application support Safari to

Comment: well, is not supported (http://iswebrtcreadyyet.com). What I used is this: http://socket.io/blog/socket-io-p2p. This implementation allow me to use p2p (webrtc) when is supported and websocket in other case.

Comment: only my video chat does'nt support safari browser. ... i want a solution in which video chat supports safari browser to.

Comment: It is not supported, so there is nothing you can do to make it supported... What I have suggested to you is to use the socket.io p2p implementation that use webrtc if supported, websocket if not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, Safari doesn't support WebRTC and you can't do anything from JavaScript.

Although you can instruct your users to install a Safari plugin to enable WebRTC support, like https://temasys.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/TWPP/overview.

Comment: It seems that the link has changed. I updated it.

Answer (score 0):

Good news everyone, things are about to change.

Apple announced support for WebRTC in Safari 11.

You can download the latest beta version of Safari 11 at the following link:
(You need to sign in with your Apple ID) https://developer.apple.com/safari/download/